# Safe call on last property in a variable chain

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception

Reading about [Null Safety in Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) and am curious why variable chains such as `bob?.department?.head?.name` never end in `?` - to check if the last property accessed is not null (in this case `name`).

I'm doing [Nullable Types on Kotlin Koans](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Nullable%20types/Task.kt) and am curious why the answer can't be:

```
fun sendMessageToClient(client: Client?, message: String?, mailer: Mailer){
    val email = client?.personalInfo?.email?
    if (message != null){ mailer.sendMessage(email, message) }
}

class Client (val personalInfo: PersonalInfo?)
class PersonalInfo (val email: String?)
interface Mailer {
    fun sendMessage(email: String, message: String)
}
```

instead of (the answer):

```
fun sendMessageToClient(client: Client?, message: String?, mailer: Mailer){
    val email = client?.personalInfo?.email
    if (message != null && email != null){ mailer.sendMessage(email, message) }
}

class Client (val personalInfo: PersonalInfo?)
class PersonalInfo (val email: String?)
interface Mailer {
    fun sendMessage(email: String, message: String)
}
```

Comment: There are `?.` and `?:` operators in Kotlin that works with expressions. The `?` alone does make sense only as nullability marker on a type name (not on an expression) and in `as?` operator

Answer (score 1):

You still have to do what to do if email is null or not null. Throw an exeption? return? Execute an else block? What?

Two alternative ways to write the answer, and that are close to what you would like, would be

```
client?.personalInfo?.email ?.let { email ->
  if (message != null) { mailer.sendMessage(email, message) }
}
```

and

```
val email = client?.personalInfo?.email ?: return
if (message != null) { mailer.sendMessage(email, message) }
```

Comment: My first suggested answer does check if email is null or not null in the if statement.

Comment: There is only one suggested answer (in addition to the actual answer of the koan) in your question. And it doesn't check if email is null. Anyway, if the email of the personalInfo of the client is null, then the value of `client?.personalInfo?.email` is null. Nothing bad will happen by declaring a value of a nullable type and assigning null to it. `?.` is useful because `client.personalInfo` would throw an exception if  client is null. But a null email won't throw any exception. So adding a `?` at the end doesn't serve any purpose. What do you think it should do?

Comment: Why wouldn't a null email throw any exception? What if `personalInfo` is not null but `email` is null? - then wouldn't you need `client?.personalInfo?.email?` ?

Comment: `val foo = null` doesn't throw any exception. Why would it? What causes an exception is calling a method or accessing a property of a null reference: `somethingNull.foo()`

Comment: I understand now. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of ?. is maybe a bit different than what you think it is. All it does is navigate over nullables.

So bob?.department gives you a Department? If instead, you used bob.department, you would get a compile error because department is nullable in bob.

The chain cannot end with ?, since ***there is no ? operator***. You can use ?. or ?:

You have 3 options:

1. Store the result of the chain into a variable of type Something?
2. Terminate the chain by using the ?: operator. In this case you have to provide an alternative for the case that the value is null (also called default value)
3. Continue the chain with ?.let {}. The code in the lambda will only be executed if the result of the chain is not null

Comment: Right I get you. There is no point of ending the chain in `?` as the compiler will detect if the final variable in the chain is null?

Comment: The compiler will detect that the final value might be null. Therefore, it will store the result in a nullable type. bob?.department gives Department?, because bob might have been null in the first place.